# Why is ruby returning array type instead of attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

I have this code in my view

```
<% @items.each do |i| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= i.name %></td>
  </tr>
<%end%>
```

and this code in my controller

```
  @categories = Category.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE users_id =#{session[:user_id]}")
  @categories.each do |c|
    @items << (Item.where(:categorys_id => c.id))
  end
```

and when I run it, the code generates a page looking like this:
"Your username is a Item Item Item"
instead of 
"Your username is a Digital Fortress Oceans Eleven Settlers"

Comment: In your /console, when you run your controller code, what array is returned? Also couldn't you do `@categories = Category.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", session[:user_id]]) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be done like this:

> Item.where(:categorys_id => c.id).**first**

`Item.where` returns a scope, it doesn't actually construct or run the query.

Methods `first` and `last` will run the query with `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` and will return the element.

Methods like `each` and `all` construct and run the query and return the array of results.

**Code review**

Your controller code is prone to SQL injection, image if something evil was in `session[:user_id]`. `"#{stuff}"` does not do any escaping of `stuff` in Ruby.

To get rid of the injection problem:

`ruby
@categories = Category.where(:users_id => session[:user_id]) # Are you sure the column is not user_id but users_id?`

The second thing we should do is to avoid doing N + 1 query where N is the number of resulting categories.

An OK way to do this is by using the SQL `IN` operator.
`ruby
@items = Item.where(:categorys_id => @categories.map(&:id)) #`

Comment: That just gives me a nil object.
I have Users table which has many Types which has many Items. I want to show all Items of all Types that the current user owns.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your controller code as follows:

```
@categories = Category.find_all_by_user_id(session[:user_id], :include => :items)
@items      = @categories.map(&:items).flatten
```

Now in your view:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.name %></td>
  </tr>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Item.where(:categorys_id => c.id)` will give you an ActiveRecord object, not an individual attributes. So when you iterate over these, `i` is an `Item` object, not an attribute.

Let's say you really wanted to output the item's `name` field, then you would do this:

```
<% @items.each do |i| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= i.name %></td>
  </tr>
<%end%>
```

Comment: That is what I have already done (I missed the .name copying it across and have edited it now)

Comment: Won't `Item.where` return an array when the argument is a hash? Which would mean `@items <<`  is appending an array, not an Item